# LTI state-space model discretization using Modelica integralExp function not working

Tags: matrix, modelica, exponential, openmodelica, discretization

I need to perform a ZOH discretization of a continuous LTI state-space model in OpenModelica (OMEdit).
I tried two ways of doing this:

1. using matrix exponential (*Matrices.exp* function) for calculating discretized A matrix (A<sub>d</sub>) and subsequent calculation of discretized B matrix (B<sub>d</sub>) following equation: *B<sub>d</sub> = A<sup>-1</sup> (A<sub>d</sub> - I) B*, where *I* is identity matrix; This algebraic equation can be solved either by direct calculation of matrix inversion (*Matrices.inv* function) or, more efficiently, by solving for *B<sub>d</sub>* matrix using *Matrices.solve2* function: `Bd = Matrices.solve2(A,(Ad-identity(2)))`, thus avoiding calculation of matrix inversion. However, in both cases *A* matrix must be invertible, what generally (and very often) doesn't hold.
2. using *Matrices.integralExp* function which should return both discretized matrices (A<sub>d</sub>, B<sub>d</sub>) and should work for general matrix *A*, whether invertible or singular; However, this function does not work for me - it returns error message: "*No viable alternative near token: (*".

I attach code for both methods for demonstration purpose. The state space model represents a very simple second-order system of linearized pendulum with length 1 m, mass 1 kg and gravitational acceleration 9.81 m/s<sup>2</sup>. Sampling time for discretization is 0.1 s. The first code works fine (*A* is invertible in this particular case) but the second code doesn't. Does anybody know what am I doing wrong? I'd be grateful for any advice.

method #1:

```
model ssDiscretization
  import Modelica.Math.Matrices;
  // Continuous LTI state-space model of pendulum: L=1, m=1, g=9.81
  Real A[2,2] = [0, 1; -9.81, 0] "system matrix";
  Real B[2,1] = [0; 1] "input matrix";
  // Discretization with sampling time 0.1 s
  Real Ad[2,2] = Matrices.exp(A,0.1) "T = 0.1 s";
  Real Bd[2,1] = Matrices.inv(A)*(Ad - identity(2))*B;
end ssDiscretization;
```

method #2:

```
model ssDiscretization
  import Modelica.Math.Matrices;
  // Continuous LTI state-space model of pendulum: L=1, m=1, g=9.81
  Real A[2,2] = [0, 1; -9.81, 0] "system matrix";
  Real B[2,1] = [0; 1] "input matrix";
  // Discretization with sampling time 0.1 s
  Real Ad[2,2];
  Real Bd[2,1];
  (Ad,Bd) = Matrices.integralExp(A,B,0.1) "T = 0.1 s";
end ssDiscretization;
```

Oliver

Comment: Not of real help, but `(Ad,Bd) = Matrices.integralExp(A,B,0.1) "T = 0.1 s";` gives the same result as the first code snippet when run from Dymola's "Commands" line. So it seems to be an issue related to the tool, not the usage... I can't give any advice on OpenModelica though...

Comment: Good to know that the code works in Dymola. Maybe somebody will give suggestion why it doesn't work when I run it in OMEdit. Thank you, Markus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the equation keyword in example 2. It still won't work in OpenModelica since it seems to have a problem with the alias `na=size(A,1)` in that function but you could easily fix the source code to make that work.

```
model ssDiscretization
  import Modelica.Math.Matrices;
  // Continuous LTI state-space model of pendulum: L=1, m=1, g=9.81
  Real A[2,2] = [0, 1; -9.81, 0] "system matrix";
  Real B[2,1] = [0; 1] "input matrix";
  // Discretization with sampling time 0.1 s
  Real Ad[2,2];
  Real Bd[2,1];
equation // This was missing
  (Ad,Bd) = Matrices.integralExp(A,B,0.1) "T = 0.1 s";
end ssDiscretization;
```

Comment: The problem is solved, thank you. Actually I didn't forget to put the `equation` keyword in the 2nd example, I did it deliberatly since I thought it should work without the equation/algorithm section the same way as the 1st example. Now I know I was wrong. But as you suggested, putting the last equation in the equation section did not solve the problem. I also had to fix the code of the integralExp function. The fix comprised rewriting the line `input Real A[:, size(A, 1)];` to `input Real A[:,:];` and similarly, rewriting the line `input Real B[size(A, 1), :];` to `input Real B[:,:];`.

Comment: It should now also work in the OpenModelica nightly builds without changing the standard library: https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/commit/9b527bc6bf